# In python, is there an easy way to turn numbers with commas into an integer, and then back to numbers with commas?

Tags: python, string, math

Let's say I have a number like this:

**8,741** or **8,741,291**

How can I use python to multiply that number by 2, and then put commas back into it?
I want the python function to return

**17,482 and 17,482,582**, in a string format.

Answer (score 11):

```
my_str = '1,255,000'

my_num = int(my_str.replace(',','')) #replace commas with nothing
```

this will return my_num = 1255000

```
result = my_num * 2

import locale
locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, 'en_US')
my_str = locale.format("%d", result, grouping=True)
```

this will return->my_str='2,510,000'

Comment: You missed the quotes in the first example and so you create a tuple.

Answer (score 6):

The first part is easy:

```
temp = "8,741,291".replace(',', '')
n = int(temp) * 2
```

I thought getting the commas back is a little harder, but it's really not!

If you are using a recent version of Python you can use the new `.format()` string method like so:

```
s = "{0:,}".format(n)
```

If you are using Python more recent than 2.6 you can omit the `0` from the curly braces in this example.  (Alas, I must use Cygwin, and alas, it only gives 2.6, so I'm used to typing the `0`.)

The specification mini-language for the `.format()` method is here:

http://docs.python.org/library/string.html#formatstrings

@user1474424 explained the `locale.format()` function, which is cool; I didn't know about that one.  I checked the docs; this has been around since Python 1.5!

http://docs.python.org/library/locale.html